# Finding the GCD of three numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms

I have found an algorithm called the [Binary GCD/Stein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm) Algorithm which takes two non-negative integers and finds the greatest common factor of the two.

What I am trying to do is take three numbers and find if each pair is relatively prime (where the GCD is one). For example, if I have non-negative variables `a` `b` and `c`, then:

```
a = 1
b = 1
c = 2
```

Would satisfy this because none of these numbers have a GCD that is larger than one. Using a variation of the Stein Algorithm in **Java**, I would like to be able to find the GCD of all three pairs of numbers (`ab` `bc` `ac`) with each side being able to go up to five, for the sake of simplicity.

Is there a way I could tweak the algorithm to compute the GCD of three numbers, or would I have to compute three groups of two pairs?

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Please note, there is an example of the implementation of this algorithm, in Java, on the link above.

Comment: If you treat $\gcd$ as an operator, much like addition or multiplication, it's commutative and associative.

Comment: you could call your gcd function twice $d={\rm gcd}(a,b)$, $e={\rm gcd}(d,c)$

Comment: It may be commutative if I have two of the same number, but if the sides are 11,6,1, I don't see how they could be commutative. Maybe I am misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: @yoyo I suppose I could, I was just hoping someone had an idea that would make my program one step shorter. :)

Comment: $\gcd(a,b,c) = \gcd(\gcd(a,b),c) = \gcd(a,\gcd(b,c))=\gcd(\gcd(a,c),b)$

Comment: ^ Like that, that would most certainly work, and I do believe that is what @J.M. was trying to say. I guess I wasn't really thinking that, if one pair isn't relatively prime, than it doesn't matter what the others are.

Comment: A quick warning: unless there are more conditions on _a_, _b_, _c_, the GCD of all three numbers **will not** give you the information you need. gcd(_a_, _b_, _c_) = 1 doesn't imply that gcd(_a_, _b_) = gcd(_a_, _c_) = gcd(_b_, _c_) = 1; for example, let _a_ = 1 and _b_ = _c_ = 3.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As others say, one way to do it is using the identity $\gcd(a,b,c)=\gcd(a,(\gcd(b,c))$.
This identity is true since the "gcd" is the maximal element of the intersection of the sets of factors of the inputs. For example, taking $\gcd(6,10)$, the set of factors of $6$ is {$6, 3, 2, 1$}, the set of factors of $10$ is {$10, 5, 2, 1$}, their intersection is {$2, 1$}, and the maximal element is $2$. The identity follows since intersections of sets are commutative and associative.

However, it's also possible to extend Stein's algorithm to handle more than two inputs. Wikipedia gives 5 steps to Stein's algorithm, and we can change them to the following to compute the gcd of a set $S$ of numbers:

1. If anything in $S$ is zero, remove it.
2. If everything in $S$ is even, divide everything in $S$ by 2, and then multiply the final answer by 2 at the end.
3. If some numbers in $S$ are even and some are odd, divide all the even numbers by 2.
4. If every number in $S$ is odd, then choose an arbitrary element of $S$ and call it $k$. Replace every other element, say $n$, with $|n-k|/2$.
5. Repeat steps 1–4 until there is only one remaining element in $S$. After you remember to multiply in the twos that you got from step 2, that's your gcd!

Comment: I do believe that this algorithm takes the minimal element of the intersection, doesn't it?

Comment: This answer has a **mistake** in it! In step 4, one should choose the **smallest element**, and not an arbitrary one.
I have tried to edit the answer twice, both tries were rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is J.M. s algorithm implemented as a c++ template class

```
// Template for GCD
template<typename AType> AType VARGCD(int nargs, ...)
{
    va_list arglist;
    va_start(arglist, nargs);

    AType *terms = new AType[nargs];
    AType result = 0;

    // put values into an array
    for (int i = 0; i < nargs; i++) 
    {
        terms[i] = va_arg(arglist, AType);
        if (terms[i] < 0)
        {
            va_end(arglist);
            return (AType)0;
        }
    }
    va_end(arglist);

    int shift = 0;
    int numEven = 0;
    int numOdd = 0;
    int smallindex = -1;

    // Step 1 count number of even and odd
    do
    {
        numEven = 0;
        numOdd = 0;
        smallindex = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < nargs; i++)
        {
            if (terms[i] == 0)
                continue;

            if (terms[i] & 1)
                numOdd++;
            else
                numEven++;

            if ((smallindex < 0) || terms[i] < terms[smallindex])
            {
                smallindex = i;
            }
        }

        // check for exit
        if (numEven + numOdd == 1)
            continue;

        // If everything in S is even, divide everything in S by 2, and then multiply the final answer by 2 at the end.
        if (numOdd == 0)
        {
            shift++;
            for (int i = 0; i < nargs; i++)
            {
                if (terms[i] == 0)
                    continue;

                terms[i] >>= 1;
            }
            continue;
        }

        // If some numbers in S  are even and some are odd, divide all the even numbers by 2.
        if (numEven > 0 && numOdd > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < nargs; i++)
            {
                if (terms[i] == 0)
                    continue;

                if ((terms[i] & 1)  == 0) 
                    terms[i] >>= 1;
            }
            continue;
        }

        //If every number in S is odd, then choose an arbitrary element of S and call it k.Replace every other element, say n, with | n−k / 2.
        if (numEven == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < nargs; i++)
            {
                if (i == smallindex || terms[i] == 0)
                    continue;

                terms[i] = abs(terms[i] - terms[smallindex]) >> 1;
            }
        }

    } while (numEven + numOdd > 1);

    // only one remaining element multiply the final answer by 2s at the end.
    for (int i = 0; i < nargs; i++)
    {
        if (terms[i] == 0)
            continue;

        return terms[i] << shift;
    }

    return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the c++ code to find the gcd (greatest common divisor) of three numbers:

```
    #include <iostream.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    void main()
    {
      int x,y,z;
      int d,i;
      cout<<"enter three numbers: ";
      cin>>x>>y>>z;
      d=1;
      i=1;

      //condition required

      while(i<=x&&i<=y&&i<=z)
        {
          if(x%i==0&&y%i==0&&z%i==0)
            {
              d=i;
            }
            i++;

        }

      cout<<"GCD: "<<d;
      getch(); 
}
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/81101/